# How to login using django & mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, authentication, django-views

I have coding challenge must use technologies:
 - Python/Django
 - Backend : Django
 - Frontend : Angular
 - Database : MongoDB
I found some problems in login,
in django how i can login using database mongodb

views

```
def auth_login(request, on_success='/', on_fail='/account/login'):  
user = authenticate(username=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return redirect(on_success)
else:
    return redirect(on_fail)
```

Error : 
**settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.**

Comment: post the database settings in settings.py.

Comment: @aircraft 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'products.backend.AuthBackend', )

from mongoengine import *
connect('shops')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct configuration of mongodb database in [settings](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'your-database',
        'USER': 'your-databaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'your-password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 'the-port',
    }
}
```

---

Django uses dummy if the database ENGINE setting is empty (None or empty string).

and it raise Exception:

```
ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
                       "Please supply the ENGINE value. Check "
                       "settings documentation for more details.")
```

So, your error is caused by setting the ENGINE to `django.db.backends.dummy`

Comment: Thank you i think it support just python 2.x
i'm using 3 but np i will use 2.x

Comment: But port must be an int instead of a string